# Graph Theory: prove the defect version of Hall's theorem

Tags: graph-theory, bipartite-graphs

[image]

i don't really understand the expression delta(A), and i don't understand how exactly and in what way i am supposed to bound the matching number of G.

Comment: What is $N(S)$?

Comment: Do you understand Hall's Theorem itself?